# Hi when i try to capture the date from a text box it was not capture when i try to watch that parameter it was showing error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi when i try to capture the date from a text box it was not capture when i try to watch that parameter it was showing error

> (Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point
>   where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code is
>   optimized.)

```
DateTime logstartdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Text);
DateTime logenddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Text);

DateTime logfdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Text);
DateTime logtdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Text);
DateTime stdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstartdate.Text);

DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstartdate.Text);
DateTime closedate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtenddate.Text);
if (logfdate <= stdate && stdate >= logtdate)
{
    lblmessage.Visible = true;
    lblmessage.Text = "Sorry!start date must be in between the log start date and log end date";
    return;
}
```

Comment: At what line you are facing this?

Comment: when i move my mouse over the date parameter it was showing like that